# Did Putin publicly condemn the blockade of Nagorno-Karabakh?

Tags: human-rights, vladimir-putin, azerbaijan, armenia

Recently Putin [compared](https://youtu.be/JDfpdmEYd_0?t=217) the siege of Gaza with that of Leningrad (during WW2), in order to express his concern about the civilian population there.

I've been trying to find what terms of comparison Putin might have used during the [blockade of Nagorno-Karabakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockade_of_Nagorno-Karabakh). I was able find this (rather mildly worded, IMHO) [statement](https://www.reuters.com/world/kremlin-says-it-is-concerned-about-karabakh-road-blockade-will-continue-talks-2022-12-29/) from his press office:

> In response to a question from reporters, Kremlin spokesman Dmitry Peskov said: "We are concerned about the tension that has arisen around the Lachin corridor, and the Russian side will continue its efforts, both in contacts with Yerevan and in contacts with Baku."

Did Putin *himself* however say anything about the humanitarian situation in Karabakh?

Comment: Did anyone said anything about this blockade? I only learned about it in September 2023. I read significant amount of press.

Comment: @alamar: yeah, sure, of the kind that says Navalny=Zionists, based on your other recent comments.

Comment: A week ago I would not have said that, but recent Palestine events made it apparent that Russian anti-war opposition are in fact Israeli nationalist war mongers. I mean, have you seen what they are saying about it?